# ARCore issue for normal use

Tags: android, arcore

Actually I am working in **ARCore** API but the problem is Arcore is only work on few selected devices **(Pixel series and Samsung 8 series)**. And ARCore preview comes out by google.

So I am asking that is there any way you can run the Apps intrigated with ARCore in your normal device with Nougat. And is there any ARCore preview 1 because recently google launch ARCore preview 2.

Is there any ARCore preview 1 which will work on all the other devices so that I can perform my test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARCore Compatible devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374494/arcore-compatible-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [ARCore For All](https://github.com/tomthecarrot/arcore-for-all) for testing. I wouldn't recommend releasing any apps that use ARCore For All. From what I have heard there may be a way to install ARCore prerequisites on a device when downloading an ARCore app if the ARCore prerequisites aren't already installed - but that would be when ARCore v1 officially launches.

Comment: you are saying that if I publish that application on Google Play. So the ARCore will work on normal devices as well?? @nerk

Comment: @Praveen no. I don&amp;#39;t know what you mean by normal devices. You may be able to install the necessary ARCore apk on A SUPPORTED device if it isn&amp;#39;t already installed once v1 is released, which could still be months away ( probably within next 2 months). Edit: in other words, there is no mass arcore adoption at this point. Plus, you want to be using preview 2 at this point. It's much better.

Comment: normal devices means android devices other then (pixel series and samsung s series)

Comment: actually I recently made an Android Application using ARCore library. But I am unable to test it because I don't have pixel or samsung s. To test my app I need to install arcorePreciew.apk and my xyz.apk in pixel devices ?? @nerk

Comment: Check out arcore for all...see if your device is supported

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late, but this may help someone. The ARCore Preview 1 APK can be found at this link: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases/download/sdk-preview/arcore-preview.apk

Google doesn't actually have this link on their site, but you can modify the URL for their Preview 2 APK to find this one.

Comment: is this work on normal device. I mean expect pixel series and samsung series as mention in google ocumentain

Comment: ARCore only supports the devices that Google has announced as it is still currently in Developer Preview, check out their GitHub issues for more support: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/89